# Script Works in Powershell CLI but not in ISE or as a PS1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

When I run the script inside ISE(as admin) I get error:

```
Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'W02439'
+ $WGUID = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $W).ObjectGUID
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (W02439:ADComputer) [Get-ADComputer], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

Running in Powershell I get expected output, of GUID numbers which I double checked are the correct id's.

```
$WNumbers = 
'
W02418,
W02427,
W02430,
W02434,
W02438,
W02439
'

$WNumbers = $WNumbers.Replace("`n",'')
$WNumbers = $WNumbers.Trim()
$WNumbers = $WNumbers.Split(",")

$WNumbers

foreach($W in $WNumbers) {
$WGUID = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $W).ObjectGUID
Write-Host $WGUID
#Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $AOGUID -Members $WGUID -WhatIf
}
```

I thought maybe ISE didn't have ActiveDirectory so I originally put Import-Module ActiveDirectory - this did not solve it.
I also tried restarting ISE, running it not as admin, neither worked.
However when I run:

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity "W02418"
```

It works as expected. So I assume my problem is it doesn't let me pass variables into -Identity inside ISE engine vs PS.
(Normally the Numbers would be stored in a file and read in etc, but I wanted to simplify the code to where the problem seems to be, and that being to passing a variable into -Identity)

Comment: $wnumbers may have `\`r` in them as well.

Comment: Build your array the proper way: `$WNumbers = 'W02418','W02427','W02430','W02434','W02438','W02439'` and if you do want to split the computernames from a string like that, remember that Windows uses CRLF for newlines: `$WNumbers =  = $WNumbers -split '\r?\n' -split ',' -ne ''`

Comment: @js2010 That fixed it, thank you! I feel dumb, the CLI wouldn't see that as they are all separate lines while the "Text Editor" ISE would. Once again, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Theo formatting it that way was done so I could actually implement split, replace etc. I just wanted to get familiar with how the methods worked. Also thanks for the code snippet, the one line will be much nicer than my multiple.

Answer (score 1):

$wnumbers may have "`r" in them as well.  It may not show up in the console.  I knew scripts vs the console were different in line endings, but not ise vs console.

```
$WNumbers = 
'
W02418,
W02427,
W02430,
W02434,
W02438,
W02439
'
$WNumbers = $WNumbers.Replace("`n",'')
$WNumbers -replace '\r','\r'

\rW02418,\rW02427,\rW02430,\rW02434,\rW02438,\rW02439\r
```

I would do:

```
$WNumbers = -split 'W02418
W02427
W02430
W02434
W02438
W02439'
```

Or

```
$WNumbers = echo W02418 W02427 W02430 W02434 W02438 W02439
```